# Exporting / Importing Object with Animations

Tags: animation, rigging, export, import

I've been trying to work on a bow and arrow and get it working inside unity. I don't have much experience with animations, but I've successfully got my characters to run, walk, idle, attack, get hit, mine rocks, cut trees etc. Today I finished rigging my bow and got it all animated. I tried exporting it as a .FBX and importing it into another project I have with the character rigged already with a pulling the bow string back and releasing. When exporting the bow, everything works great, the key-frames are perfect just like they should be but after importing into another project or even a blank blend file, my animation always adds extra key-frames and totally messes with the animation. I've spent over 2 hours trying every possible configuration I could think of inside the settings and more that definitely made no sense but I tried for the hell of it. Has this happened to anybody before? Any help, knowledge or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks ahead of time and have a great weekend!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will have to do the animations in the 'dope sheet' tab.

If you still do not know, I'll show you how it works.

Basically, it is equal to timeline. But here, you can define several separate animations, and each one will have its own name.

To access the 'Dope sheet' tab, pull a new tab and select it.
[image]

Now you will have to switch to 'action editor', because this is where you can name animations and do other things.
[image]

Click New and type a name for your animation.
[image]

Check the F box so that the animations are saved in your project, so you will not risk losing them when you leave the blender and open the project again another time.
[image]

Now, do a little simple animation and export again to see if everything will work fine.

If you want to create more animations, just select + next to F.

Comment: Elektro Jaroski, this did not work. When exporting as I usually export, there are only 2-3 of my 9 key-frames. Also my armature no longer works and I'm missing at least 1 bone that I can see.

Comment: If you can import your .blend file so I can see what's really going on, it would be a lot better to find the solution.

Comment: MY BLEND FILE https://ufile.io/aa26r

Comment: See if this animation works correctly. https://www.mediafire.com/file/1z14u5yeitflpp4/bow_editing2.fbx

Comment: Nope, same as when I export it. The animation is broken, can no longer demonstrate inside of pose mode. Also there is still added key-frames. I don't understand it. I have no idea why this could be happening.

Comment: To preview the animation after it has imported, you have to set the final keyframe to a higher value because it is set to 1. Put 50 and it will be working. Now about 'additional keyframes', you can delete them, your animation will continue to function properly. https://imgur.com/7d0mkYV , https://imgur.com/8ZpDFFP , https://imgur.com/lp2Dus1

Comment: Yea but I'm not looking for a workaround I'm trying to find the answer to the problem. Moving forward I'll always have to work with animations and its a complete waste of time editing something after its 100% completed.